# Python, searching own codes wrote

Tags: python

There are scripts wrote and all of them may of different topics. Some about documents handling, some about text extraction, some about automation.

Sometimes I forgot a usage, for example how to create a .xls file, so I want to search if in the scripts there is a line about how to do it.

What I am doing is to convert all the .py files into .txt, and combine all txt files together. Then I use Word to open this aggregated .txt file and find.

What’s the better way to search specific lines in own written codes?

**converting .py to .txt:

```
folder = "C:\\Python27\\"

for a in os.listdir(folder):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(a)
    if ext == ".py":
        os.rename(folder + a, folder + root + ".txt")
```

**putting all .txt together:

```
base_folder = "C:\\TXTs\\"
all_files = []
for each in os.listdir(base_folder):
    if each.endswith('.txt'):
        kk = os.path.join(base_folder, each)
        all_files.append(kk)

with open(base_folder + " final.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in all_files:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: you can use regex

Comment: @Julien, thank you. use regex to read the big txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep all of your code in a single directory tree, e.g. `code`.

If your operating system doesn't have a decent search tool like `grep`, install "[the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)". (You will also need a decent terminal emulator.)

For example (I'm using FreeBSD here), I tend to keep all my source code under `src/`. If I want to know in which scripts I use xls files, I type:

```
ag xls src/
```

Which retuns:

```
src/progs/uren/project-uren.py
24:    print("Usage: {} urenbriefjesNNNN.xlsm project".format(binary),
```

This tells me to look at line 24 of the file `src/progs/uren/project-uren.py`.

If I e.g. search for `Counter`:

```
ag Counter src/
```

I get multiple hits:

```
src/scripts/public/csv2tbl.py
13:from collections import Counter
45:    letters, sep = Counter(), Counter()

src/scripts/public/dvd2webm.py
15:from collections import Counter
94:    rv = Counter(re.findall('crop=(\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)', proc.stderr))

src/scripts/public/scripts-tests.py
14:from collections import Counter
26:    v = Counter(rndcaps(100000)).values()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install rStudio, an open source IDE for the r language. In the Edit menu there is a `Find in File...` feature you can use just like find and replace in a word document. It will go through files in the directory you point it to...I have not yet had problems searching scripts as they are, untransformed to txt. It will search for terms or regex expressions....it is pretty useful!

As is R!

Answer (score 1):

`cat *.py | grep xls` if you're on Linux.
Otherwise it may be helpful to keep some sort of README file with your python scripts. I, personally, prefer Markdown:

```
## Scripts
They do stuff  
### Script A  
Does stuff A, call `script_a.py -h` for more info  
### Script B  
Does stuff B, call `script_b.py -h` for more info
```

It compiles to this:

### Scripts

They do stuff

#### Script A

Does stuff A, call `script_a.py -h` for more info

#### Script B

Does stuff B, call `script_b.py -h` for more info

It takes basically no time to write and Markdown can be easily used on sites such as SO, Github, Reddit and others. This very answer, in fact, is written in Markdown. But if you can't be bothered with Markdown, a simple `README.txt` is still much better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The technical term for what you're trying to do is a "full text file search". Googling this together with your operating system name will give you many methods. Here is one for Windows: https://www.howtogeek.com/99406/how-to-search-for-text-inside-of-any-file-using-windows-search/.

If you're on MacOS I recommend looking into BASH command line syntax to do a bit more complex automation tasks (although what you need is also perfectly covered in Spotlight search). On Windows 10 you could check out the new Linux Subsystem that gives you the same syntax [1]. Composing small commands together using pipes and xargs in command line is a very powerful automation tool. For what you're asking I still think a full text search is the most straightforward solution, but since you're already into programming I thought I bring this up.

To demonstrate, the task you describe would be something like

```
find . -name "*.py" | xargs -I {} grep -H "xls" {}
```

This would search your working directory (and all subdirectories) for python files (using `.` as its first argument to `find`, which refers to the directory you're currently in, shown by `pwd`), and then search each of those python files for the string "xls". `xargs` takes all lines from standard input (which the pipe `|` gets from the last command) and converts them into command line parameters. `grep -H` searches files for the specified string and prints the occurrences together with the file name.

[1] I'm assuming you're not on Linux already since you like to use MS Office.

Comment: thank you for the knowledge. you are indeed a scientist. hope you don't mind I choose another reply for the answer.